# reproject vector layer with pyqgis with new CRS does not worl

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis, geojson

In QGIS I am running a script in th python toolbar to export all visible vector layers to a GEOJSON with this snippet:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
allLayers = canvas.layers()
for i in allLayers: 

    if i.type() != 0 :
        print(i.name() + " skipped as it is not a vector layer")  
    if i.type() == 0 :
        exp_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326,QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.PostgisCrsId)
        print i.crs()
        print exp_crs
        qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i, '/home/' + str(i.name()) + '.js', 'utf-8', exp_crs, 'GeoJson')
```

If my vector file has a different CRS it keeps using the vector file CRS and doesn't use the defined CRS EPSG:4326... What am I doing wrong?
The whole project context can be found on [GITHUB](https://github.com/riccardoklinger/qgis2leaf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main problem was the setting of the crs.
this snippet should work now:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
allLayers = canvas.layers()
exp_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
for i in allLayers: 

    if i.type() != 0 :
        print(i.name() + " skipped as it is not a vector layer")  
    if i.type() == 0 :
        #exp_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326,QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.PostgisCrsId)
        print i.crs()
        print exp_crs
        qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i, i.name() + '.js', 'utf-8', exp_crs, 'GeoJSON')
```